# Is one permitted to fly a kite on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, games-toys

Is one permitted to fly a kite on Shabbat? Assuming that there is an Eiruv, would it be permitted?

Answer (score 7):

[Dinonline Flying a Kite on shabbat](http://dinonline.org/2016/04/28/flying-a-kite-on-shabbat/) answers,

> The actual flying of a kite itself does not involve a Shabbos
> prohibition [when there is an eruv]. However, this is not a
> recommended activity on Shabbos. Very often a kite has to be fixed,
> put together or reattached, all of which are prohibited on Shabbos. In
> addition the string often becomes knotted and may not be undone on
> Shabbos. It is also likely that this activity is not in the spirit of
> Shabbos
>
> The Mishna in Beitzah 36b lists a number of things prohibited by
> Rabbinic law as they may lead to Shabbos transgression. Logic would
> dictate that this activity should be included as well. However we do
> not have the authority to add new *gzeirot* (decrees), and so this
> activity can not be strictly prohibited.