# Holding a Helium Balloon on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, eruv-chatzerot

Inspired by [Is one permitted to fly a kite on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83126/is-one-permitted-to-fly-a-kite-on-shabbat)

That question asks about a situation where there is an eiruv. I assume that the concern is carrying the kite to the place where it will be flown and not whether "flying" is the same as "carrying" (though I may be wrong). It also begs the question if whether the kite strays by dint of its string's length over an area outside the eiruv if that is a problem but I am wondering something different:

Can I walk outside (where there is no eiruv) on Shabbat holding a string attached to a [helium](https://dinonline.org/2011/01/25/helium-balloon-muktzeh/) balloon?

While I am securing it, I am not keeping it UP and defying gravity (carrying) but holding it down. Is that hotza'ah? If I were to be holding 10 or 15 balloons, then controlling them and keeping them from escaping would take effort, but does that become a melacha?

If the string unties, the balloon flies away (no fixing) but then I am carrying the string, so is the balloon actually keeping me from doing the melacha? If so, can I attach other things to the balloon and "not carry" them because the balloon is doing the work?

Comment: Presumably this would be contingent on the height of the balloon+string, since objects above a certain height are not considered in the public domain. See *gemara Shabbos* re: things extending downward from a non-public space into a public space.

Comment: Even rolling something through a public domain is hotzaa. I don't see what gravity has to do with anything

Comment: @DoubleAA but that's because the object rests in the public domain - the ground. There's a machlokes about a thrown object (kelutah kemi shehunchah dami), but that primarily is because the assumption is that the object will eventually come to rest on Shabbos. The balloon can remain aloft for days, so any hanachah isn't actually occurring on shabbos...

Comment: Carrying anything whatsoever is carrying. Not much to it. What difference does it make if the balloon has a string or not? Are you not picking up the balloon and transferring it from one place to another?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't know why you say "that's because the object rests [on] the ground"

Comment: There's some nuance about "hotza'ah" that I sense in your 4th paragraph, that I think is essential to understanding the issue in your question. If that's the case, please edit that in. I think it will avoid a lot of follow-up questions.

Comment: @DoubleAA because here the object is never in the public domain. You aren't "holding the string up" off the ground, you're holding it "down." If an object rolls off a roof but never REACHES the public domain (gemara gives the example of a scroll) you can roll it back up to the roof, because even someone "picking it up" from the public domain to place back on the roof isn't actually supporting the object from the public domain. The string is supported by the buoyancy of the balloon not by the person holding it.

Comment: @DanF See the halachos of holding a rope attached to an animal - since the ANIMAL is supporting the rope, the person leading the animal is not engaged in hotza'ah of the rope. Here, the balloon is supporting teh string, not the person.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky You're just asserting a lot of things at me without addressing my comments...

Comment: @DoubleAA see my comment to DanF about the rope attached to an animal. Where the holder of the rope is not the sole support of the object we do not consider them to be carrying it. Here the string is held aloft by the balloon, not the person. Ergo, like with the leash, you are not engaging in hotzaah.

Comment: Here's a cute idea:  We use ארון נושא את נושאיו to say that this was one of the melachot of the mishkan and therefore assur.   ;)

Comment: I think the fundamental question is - can you do an akirah and a hanachah with an object that doesn't go to or stay on the ground by itself?

Answer (score 3):

As per the comment of @doubleAA, the translation of *hotzaa* as "carrying" is misleading, and "translating" or "transferring" would perhaps be more precise translations.  The *melocho* essentially concerns translating a non-moving object from a static position to a halachically distinct static position.  If the balloon and/or objects attached to the balloon are in an initial state of rest in one of two halachically distinct domains (public and private) and you directly transfer them to a static position in the other of the two domains, that is the biblical prohibition of hotzaa.  The actual weight, effort, and work are not particularly relevant to the biblical concept of the *melocho*.

Comment: See if you can provide some source for this. It is an area that, I think, confuses "learned" people - meaning people who are smart enough to admit that they don't know what they think they know. In my "humility", I include myself in that group.

Comment: Can something be halachically "at rest" if it's floating in the air?

Comment: @Nic Something can be "at rest" floating in water.